# Fine Grained Password Policy

Tags: active-directory

Do Fine Grained Password Policies (in this situation, applied to a group which will have a selection of members) override the Default Domain Policy that will be applied to all other members in the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Fine Grained Password Policies take precedence over the Default Domain Policy.